# Extract list of non-matches in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, matching

So I have two dataframes, and both have one column that represents an ID number linked to a DNA sequence, and another column has the DNA sequence. My two dataframes are either the raw data, or data that have been filtered to only include a subset of the raw data. What I'm now interested in doing is generating a .csv of all the sequences in the raw dataframe that don't have a match to the stuff in the filtered dataframe.

So as an example of the goal, I'll define a couple dataframes here with two columns (col1 and col2):

```
col1a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
col2a<-c("a","t","a","t","a","g")
col1b<-c(1,3,5,6)
col2b<-c("a","a","a","g")
df1<-data.frame(col1a,col2a)
df2<-data.frame(col1b,col2b)
```

my output wants to be this third dataframe (df3):

```
col1c <- c(2,4)
col2c <- c("t","t")
df3 <- data.frame(col1c,col2c)
```

I know I can use %in%. I can get this far:

```
IN <- sum(df1$col1a %in% df2$col1b) #Output = 4
NOTIN <- sum(!df1$col1a %in% df2$col1b) #Output = 2
```

So now I'm looking for a way to export the rows referred to from "NOTIN" such that they can be written as a table. I want to generate the example dataframe I called df3 earlier, as my output.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If df1 contains all the entries in df2, it's as simple as

```
df1[!df1$col1a %in% df2$col1b, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `anti_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("col1a" = "col1b"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `data.table` as well:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(df1, key = col1a)
df2 <- data.table(df2, key = col1b)
df1[!df2]
```

With version 1.9.5 (On [GithHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), not on CRAN yet), you can use `on =` syntax instead of setting a key :

```
df1[!df2, on = c(col1a = "col1b")]
```